# WAS 8.5 webserver configuration using IBM Http Server

Tags: webserver, websphere, load-balancing, httpserver

I'm new to Websphere and trying to create a cluster Websphere 8.5 with IBM Http Server as the webserver. My topology is different from all the examples provided by IBM : 
I have 2 physical machines : machine A and machine B.

On `machine A` : deployment manager + app server A + HTTP Server + HTTP administration server + webserver plugin

On `machine B` : app server B + webserver plugin

I have a cluster who contains appsv A and appsv B, and now I want to create a webserver on `machine A`for the cluster.

I've used the "Webserver Configuration Tool" to create a remote webserver : websv for machine B. But I don't know how to do with app server A...

Am I doing wrong? Should I configure the plug-in separately on the machines but giving the same name for the webserver so that I can migrate the cfg files to one then put it on machine A? 
How should I do with the "configwebsv.bat"?

Thanks a lot for your responses.
Allen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to do anything with a webserver or webserver plug-in on machine B. The dmgr is aware of any clusters you have and allows you to map them to your webserver no matter where it lives.